# How to solve $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(x^2+1)^n}\,\mathrm dx$ for $n\ge 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to find some closed form answer for the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(x^2+1)^n}\,\mathrm dx,\quad n\ge 2$$
I am not sure if a closed form exists and I have been trying this integral for hours.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You would have a better statement for more general, real values of $n$ by restricting to $n \gt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Sub $x=\tan{t}$ and get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} dt \, \sin^n{t} \, \cos^{n-2}{t} $$

which one may recognize as a Beta function.  Further to this, sub $y=\sin{t}$ and get

$$\int_0^1 dy \, y^n \, (1-y^2)^{\frac{n-3}{2}} = \frac12 \int_0^1 du \, u^{\frac{n-1}{2}} (1-u)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}$$

which is

$$\frac{\Gamma \left ( \frac{n+1}{2} \right ) \Gamma \left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right )}{2 \Gamma(n)} $$

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: I just wrote $(2+x^2)$ instead of $(1+x^2)$. Nothing deep.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\tan t,u=\sin t$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(x^2+1)^n}dx&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nt\cos^{n-2}tdt\\
&=&\int_0^{1}u^n(1-u^2)^{\frac{n-3}2}du\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{1}u^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{n-3}2}du
\end{eqnarray}
Then using 
$$ B(p,q)=\int_0^1u^{p-1}(1-u)^{q-1}du $$
you can easily get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both other answers have made indirect use of [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) to arrive at the integral form of

[Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). However, this can be done directly, by substituting $t=\dfrac1{x^2+1}~.~$ In fact,

all integrals of the form $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{\Big(x^p+a^p\Big)^n}~dx~$ can be evaluated by a similar approach, letting

first $~x=au,~$ and then $~t=\dfrac1{u^p+1}~,~$ finally yielding $~\dfrac{a^{k-np}}p~B\bigg(\dfrac kp~,~n-\dfrac kp\bigg),~$ which, for

integer values of *n*, can be substantially simplified by recursively employing $\Gamma(x+1)=x~\Gamma(x),~$

in conjunction with [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{n} \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}^{n}}
\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\,\Re\pars{n}\ >\ 1}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{\color{red}{n/2 + 1/2} - 1}\,\,\,\,\pars{1 + x}^{-n}\,\,\dd x
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{\pars{1 + x}^{-n} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-n \choose k}x^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n + k - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}x^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{n + k} \over \Gamma\pars{n}}{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$.

Then, with *Ramanujan's Master Theorem*,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{n} \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}^{n}}
\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\,\Re\pars{n}\ >\ 1}} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{{n \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}}
{\Gamma\pars{n - \bracks{\color{red}{n/2 + 1/2}}} \over \Gamma\pars{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{n/2 + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{n/2 - 1/2} \over 2\Gamma\pars{n}}\\ &
\end{align}