# How do I evaluate the following integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathop{dx} \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I am interested in the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathop{dx} \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m},$$ given that $m>n/2$ (this is just what I wrote so that the integral converges. If this is not exactly true, just assume that $m$ and $n$ are such that the integral converges.) It is known that $m$ and $n$ are rational numbers and $a$ is a real constant. Any body has any idea? I felt that contour integral might be a good bet. However, the problem is that for non integer $m$, there are branch points.

Comment: have you tried trigonometric substitution of x = a*tan(u)? this gives an integrand in terms of a power of sine of u over a power of cosine of u multiplied by a constant of a

Comment: The problem is that 1/cos will be divergent at end points, -pi/2 and pi/2.

Comment: If $-m\not\in\Bbb Z, \frac{n+1}{2}\not\in\Bbb Z, -m+\frac{n+1}{2}\not\in\Bbb Z$, then $\int x^n\left(x^2+a^2\right)^{-m}\, dx$ (if $m,n$ are rational) is not integrable in elementary functions.

Comment: To be more precise, $n$ is an integer, however $m$ is just a rational number.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494128) question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a\neq0$, $m-\frac{n+1}2>0 $ and $n>-1$. Then

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}=\frac{(e^{i\pi n}+1)}2\:|a|^{n-2m-1}\:\frac{\Gamma\left(m-\frac{n+1}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(m\right)}. \tag1
> $$

*Proof.*
Using the [Euler beta function $B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), you may write 
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}\\\\
& =(e^{i\pi n}+1)\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+a^2)^m}\mathop{dx}\\\\
&=(e^{i\pi n}+1)\:|a|^{n-2m-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{v^n}{(v^2+1)^m}\mathop{dv}\qquad (x=|a|\times v)\\\\
&=\frac{(e^{i\pi n}+1)}2\:|a|^{n-2m-1}\int_0^1 u^{\large m-\frac{n+1}2-1}(1-u)^{\large \frac{n+1}2-1}\mathop{du}\quad \left(u=\frac1{v^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{(e^{i\pi n}+1)}2\:|a|^{n-2m-1}B\left(m-\frac{n+1}2,\frac{n+1}2\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very like a loop integral in physics, that we do it like this(I hope it wll help): when n is odd, it is 0, when n is even, then $$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{x^n}{(x^2+a)^m}=\int _0^{\infty}d(x^2)\frac{(x^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{(x^2+a)^m}$$ then, let $y=\frac{a}{x^2+a}$, it is $$\int _0^1 a y^{-2}dy\frac{(\frac{a}{y}(1-y))^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{(\frac{a}{y})^m}=a^{\frac{n-1}{2}+1-m}\int _0^1 dy^{m-2-\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-y)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$ it is a beta-function so is $$a^{\frac{n-1}{2}+1-m} \frac{\Gamma (m-1-\frac{n-1}{2}) \Gamma (\frac{n-1}{2}+1)}{\Gamma (m)}$$, I hope I don't make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. Does this apply apply to non integer (but rational) $m$?

Comment: Yes, rational m is OK

Comment: I think ratinal n is also OK, then it is $$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{x^{n}}{(x^2+a)^m}=\int _{-\infty}^0dx  \frac{x^{n}}{(x^2+a)^m} + \int _{0}^{\infty}  dx\frac{x^{n}}{(x^2+a)^m} =((-1)^n+1)\int _0^{\infty}dx \frac{x^{n}}{(x^2+a)^m} $$